# C# Webservice and Static Variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, session

I'm having a bit of a problem and was wondering if someone could help me with this.

The problem is that the static Variable is shared between different thread calls/seasions. 
This is the original code:

```
public partial class ApplicationWSGlobal : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public static string UploadPath = @"";

    public ApplicationWSGlobal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Webmethod]
    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        ... = UploadPath;            
    }
}
```

and I'm setting the UploadPath from in the global.asax class.

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest() 
 {
     ApplicationWSGlobal.UploadPath = getData();
 }
```

I tried to resolve the problem by adding the `[ThreadStatic]` to the "UploadPath' var but it did not work. That global vars runs across all sessions and i don't want that

Is there any alternatives that i can use in this situation

I thanks for all the replies in advance!

Comment: I'm unclear as to what exactly "the problem" is...

Comment: I is bit hard to explain man but i will try my best

Comment: Which is your problem? Really, we are not mind reader...

Comment: Were you expecting multiple calls to end up maintaining state, without doing anything about that yourself?

Comment: I'm setting static variables in the global.asax file on Application_BeginRequest()
the problem is that the static variable is being shared between calls

Comment: That is how static variables are supposed to work.  They exist outside of instantiated objects.

Comment: My problem is that global vars runs across all sessions and i don't want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest storing `UploadPath` in the database. That way it's guaranteed to be global across all running sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code (Remove static modifier)

```
    public partial class ApplicationWSGlobal : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public string UploadPath = @"";

        [WebMethod]
        public void SetUploadPath(string x)
        {
            UploadPath = x;
        }

        public ApplicationWSGlobal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }
```

Comment: But how do i set that UploadPath from the global.asax then?

Comment: I have added public modifier to UploadPath  property

Comment: How can i set UploadPath from the global.asax Application_BeginRequest()?

Comment: var applicationWSGlobal = new ApplicationWSGlobal

Answer (score 1):

```
var applicationWSGlobal = new ApplicationWSGlobal
{
   UploadPath = your value
};
```